# Revoking tokens using Django rest-framework-jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm thinking of allowing a user to revoke previously issued tokens (yes, even though they are set to expire in 15 minutes), but did not find any way to do so using [DRF-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt).

Right now, I'm considering several options:

- Hope someone on SO will show me how to do this out-of-the-box ;-)
- Use the jti field as a counter, and, upon revocation, require jti > last jti.
- Add user-level salt to the signing procedure, and change it upon revocation
- Store live tokens in some Redis DB

Is any of the above the way to go?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but as I bumped into it, why didn't you use drf-jwt's JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY option as specified [here](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#additional-settings)?
Was this option not available at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We did it this way in our project:

Add `jwt_issue_dt` to User model.

Add `original_iat` to payload. So token refresh won't modify this field.

Compare `original_iat` from payload and `user.jwt_issue_dt`:

```
from calendar import timegm
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication

class CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        user = super(CustomJSONWebTokenAuthentication, self).authenticate_credentials(payload)
        iat_timestamp = timegm(user.jwt_issue_dt.utctimetuple())
        if iat_timestamp != payload['iat']:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid payload')
        return user
```

To revoke a token you just need to update the field `user.jwt_issue_dt`.

Comment: Thanks Raz. Am I correct that this method does not support multiple tokens? Although I guess you can compare the time-stamp with `><` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Yes. We needed only one valid token. But `if iat_timestamp > payload['iat']: raise` should work.